# C++ GUI how to use private data from one window in the second one

Tags: c++, qt

I have got problem in Qt. I have to make two windows:
In the first one you can click on 10 buttons and each button have to add an item(name of the button) in comboBox in the second window. But I can't refer to this comboBox. I am out of any ideas :(

I tried to make the variable protected and public, but it doesn't work. I had included `window2.h` to `window1` and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
//this is in window1
void window1::on_button1_clicked() { 
    window2::combo->addItem("button1"); 
}
```

Comment: Is the second window visible to the first window? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Add an accessor function to the first window class?

Comment: You could also try making the second window class a `friend` of the first.

Comment: Or... add a slot to the second window class(or the combobox) and later connect it to the buttons click signals

Comment: Don't post code or other relevant information as comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: @MonikaDaniel please edit your question to include any information. It helps us a lot.

Comment: Also, consider providing a [mcve], if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the button's click signals to a slot in the second window. This slot will add the information to the combobox.

To do that, you will need to distinguish the signals from each other. The best way to do this is to use a `QSignalMapper`.

```
class window1 {
    Q_OBJECT
    ... // your other definitions...
    QSignalMapper* signalMapper;
};

window1::window1 (/*your constructor's parameters*/) {
    signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this); // Will map each buttons' signals to a signal with a QString parameter.

    // You can do an iteration instead of this if your buttons are on a container.
    signalMapper->setMapping(button1, QString("button1"));
    signalMapper->setMapping(button2, QString("button2"));
    // ...
    signalMapper->setMapping(button10, QString("button10"));

    // Same comment as above applies here.
    connect(button1, SIGNAL(clicked()),
            signalMapper, SLOT(map());
    connect(button2, SIGNAL(clicked()),
            signalMapper, SLOT(map());
    // ...
    connect(button10, SIGNAL(clicked()),
            signalMapper, SLOT(map());

    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), 
            window2, SLOT(updateCombo(QString)));
}

class window2 {
    Q_OBJECT
    ... // your other definitions...
public slots:
    void updateCombo(QString);
};

void window2::updateCombo(QString str) {
    combo->addItem(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the QSignalMapper approach you could name the button objects in window1 (`setName("buttonXYZ")`), connect the clicked signals to a slot in window2 and ask for the object name of the sender (`sender()->name()`).

So in the receiving slot you could do :

```
m_combo->addItem(sender()->name());

or

if(sender()->name() == "Button1") {
   m_combo->addItem("Foo");
}
```